# Javascript Page Reset

Tags: javascript, popup, settimeout, reset

Im trying to get my page to reset to its original layout once the popup goes away after 5 seconds. I've tried setTimeOut(fullReset(true), messageHIde, 5000) but that stops the pop up from working.I know how to get it back to its original layout if it was the case of using a button. Any tips about how to get it working? My java script is below for the popup and the fullReset.

```
if ((playerChoice == "higher") && (playerCard > computerCard))

{     
 document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML ="You win!";
 document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block"; 
 setTimeout(messageHide, 5000);

    /* increase the score by 5 because the user won */
    total = total + 5;  


 }

 else if ((playerChoice == "higher") && (computerCard > playerCard))  

{  
document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML ="You lose!";
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(messageHide, 5000);


total = total - 10; 
} 

else if ((playerChoice == "equal") && (playerCard > computerCard)) 

{ document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML ="You win!";
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(messageHide, 5000);

  total = total +5 ; } 

 else if ((playerChoice == "equal") && (computerCard > playerCard)) 

 { document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML ="You lose!";
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(messageHide, 5000);

 total = total - 10;}  

 else if ((playerChoice == "lower") && (playerCard > computerCard)) 

  { 
document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML ="You win!";
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(messageHide, 5000);
total = total + 5;} 

   else if ((playerChoice =="lower") && (computerCard > playerCard))

   {document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML ="You lose!";
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";  
   setTimeout(messageHide, 5000);

      total = total - 10;}

       /* display the new total */
      alert(total + " " + playerChoice + " " + playerCard + " " +computerCard);

      document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = total;  



      }   

     function messageHide(){ 
     document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none"; 
     }     

  function fullReset(){

  document.getElementById('img1').src = 'back.gif';
  document.getElementById('img2').src = 'back.gif'; 
  document.getElementById('higherButton').style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById('lowerButton').style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
  document.getElementById('equalButton').style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById('drawButton').style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "0" +total; 
  startButton.disabled = false; 
  higherButton.disabled = true; 
  lowerButton.disabled = true; 
  equalButton.disabled = true; 
  drawButton.disabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: after document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none"; just call fullReset();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
setTimeOut(function(){
    messageHide();
    fullReset();
}, 5000);
```